# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d

Tags: python, json, xml, encoding, utf-8

i'm making a program in python that convert a the input json file in file xml, it work good for the first 560 files but than this happened:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1871: character maps to <undefined>
```

this is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##IMPORT
import codecs
import string
import sys
from src.json2xml import Json2xml
import unicodedata
import os

##FUNCTION
def fn_conversione(f):
    data = Json2xml.fromjsonfile('json//' + f).data
    data_object = Json2xml(data)
    output = data_object.json2xml() #xml output
    return (output)
def fn_letturaFile():
    filenamelist = []
    path = './json'
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        filenamelist.append(filename)
    return (filenamelist)
def fn_createXml(filenamejson, content):
    path = './xml'
    filenamexml = filenamejson.replace('.json', '.xml')
    f = open("./xml/" + filenamexml, "w+", encoding="utf8")
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
    return("scritto")
nomeFile = fn_letturaFile()
for i in range (len(nomeFile)):
    contenuto = fn_conversione(nomeFile[i])
    if contenuto != None:
        fn_createXml(nomeFile[i], contenuto)
        print(i, "/", len(nomeFile))
print(i, "/", len(nomeFile))
```

Comment: You're asking us to debug a problem that happens with a specific input file that we don't have. Please try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Not all character are mapped, e.g. with latin1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) the 0x9x characters have not valid. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set do not have 0x9d as valid code.